# Select query from XML string in MySQL

Tags: mysql, xpath

I have XML string which having multiple child nodes, i want to fetch data from child nodes below is an example structure, i want to fetch all result nodes. Trying to use this query in **MySQL**

```
SET @xml= '<aaa><result>
        <id>1</id>
        </result>
        <result>
        <id>2</id>
        </result>
         ....
    </aaa>';
SELECT  ExtractValue(@xml, '/aaa/result/id/text()[1]');
```

Current output

```
1 2
```

**Expected output**

```
1
2
```

Let me know if there is best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it by splitting the column into two columns

```
SET @xml= '<aaa><result>
        <id>1</id>
        </result>
        <result>
        <id>2</id>
        </result>
    </aaa>';

SELECT
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(ExtractValue(@xml, '//id'), ' ', 1) AS `id1`,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(ExtractValue(@xml, '//id'), ' ', -1) AS `id2`
```

**OUTPUT**

```
id1   |    id2
1     |     2
```

As you said results node can be multiple, for this I have tried below query

```
SET @xml= '<aaa><result>
        <id>1</id>
        </result>
        <result>
        <id>2</id>
        </result>
        <result>
        <id>3</id>
        </result>
        <result>
        <id>4</id>
        </result>
        <result>
        <id>5</id>
        </result>
        <result>
        <id>7</id>
        </result>
        <result>
        <id>6</id>
        </result>
        <result>
        <id>8</id>
        </result>
        <result>
        <id>9</id>
        </result>
        <result>
        <id>10</id>
        </result>
        <result>
        <id>11</id>
        </result>        
    </aaa>';

SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ExtractValue(@xml, '//id'), ' ', n.n), ' ', -1) value
  FROM (select SUBSTRING_INDEX(ExtractValue(@xml, '//id'), ' ', 1)) t CROSS JOIN 
  (
   SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
     FROM 
    (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
   ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
    ORDER BY n 
   ) n
 WHERE n.n <= 1 + (LENGTH(ExtractValue(@xml, '//id')) - LENGTH(REPLACE(ExtractValue(@xml, '//id'), ' ', '')))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Value

1
2
3
4
5
7
6
8
9
11
```

Comment: Thanks Rohan for reply, unfortunately above solution will not work because result nodes can be multiple.

Comment: @Suresh I have updated the query for multiple nodes. Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Yes Rohan updated query looks okay, i tried another solution used while loop based on ExtractValue(v_order_xml,'count(//v_order_date)') , and fetched data row by row using loop counter variable. Anyway accepting your answer. Thanks

Comment: @Suresh, Please accept the answer, still you dint accepted the answer. :-)